# django - Changes in template files are not shown

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm working on a `django` project, after changing some templates, it works on my local machine, but after uploading to production server (+restarting Apache) `webserver` shows the old code!
Its about few specific base template files.

I have tried to restart server, reload `webserver` and reinstall venv.
None of it worked.

Do I use `template/fragment` caching? **No.**
Do I use `apache's` caching? **No.**

**UPDATE :**

i just made some changes to one of another `app`'s template files and uploaded it
after refresh, it updated right away!
now **i am pretty sure** that this problem is happening to only 1 of my `apps`

Comment: Did you try removing all `__pycache__` folders?

Comment: yes. and it didnt worked

Comment: what's webserver? do you use gunicorn or uwsgi?

Comment: apache / mod_wsgi

Comment: I had the same problem, and I solved it executing: `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn-django-tutorial.service`. The changes are not shown in production because gunicorn needs to reload the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using gunicorn, I solved it this way:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn-django-tutorial.service
```

The changes are not shown in production because gunicorn needs to reload the configuration.

A restart of the web server is not needed (I'm using Nginx).